# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I just came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957836/use-upper-and-lower-cases-on-a-same-word) which is missing a Python tag, and went to edit in, but the edit link is missing. I checked a couple of other questions, and the edit link is where I'd expect.

[image: screenshot: no edit link]
[image: screenshot: edit link as normal]

Is this a bug, or am I missing something special about the situation that revokes my edit rights?

I'm using the mobile website with Chrome 43 on Android 4.0

Comment: The edit link is there for me- That said, it looks like a suggested edit was approved _right_ as you posted this. While that shouldn't disable the link for you (since you have over 2k rep and therefore would be able to review the suggestion) it may well have something to do with it. (Note that I don't know how that works on the mobile site.)

Comment: As a side note, the editor added that tag, so you won't have to worry about that now. =)

Comment: Hm, it's back for me now, too - luckily, I grabbed a screenshot so you can see I didn't just imagine it. The suggested edit must have been pending when I looked, so the edit behaviour would have been different, but it shouldn't just make the link disappear like that, surely?

Comment: I actually found another report of this on MSE, and it is apparently by-design. (And it makes sense that it is, when you really think about it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a pending edit, and is, according to [Animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) on [this MSE answer,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161023/pending-edits-remove-the-edit-link-altogether-on-mobile-site) by-desgin.

To quote a relevant part of the answer:

> The edit link is greyed out on the main site and has a tooltip that
>   displays when you hover over the edit link (for those who can't vote
>   to approve/reject it), which explains that there is a pending edit and
>   you cannot edit it.
>
> Since mobile doesn't really have any way of "hovering" to get that
>   tooltip, the edit link just isn't displayed (which used to be the
>   normal behavior on the main site when the link didn't get greyed out).

Since the suggested edit has been approved, about the time you posted this question, you should now see the edit link on mobile again.

While you do have the rep to be able to review suggested edits, [review is currently not available on mobile, at least not through normal means such as the edit link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available) Given that, the outcome would be the same for me or you, provided we looked at the same question at the same time on mobile and the question had a pending suggested edit.

Comment: That is really horrible design, but thanks for tracking down the explanation. The principle of least astonishment would surely suggest something be put in its place - or just leave it there and have the message pop up when you click instead?

Comment: Hang on, unaccepting - I have enough rep to *review* the edit, whereas that answer is about users who don't.

Comment: Well, on desktop when you can't edit the link gets disabled. That _would_ be an option, but due to the lack of hover (the reason for the link being disabled is explained in a tooltip) it would leave users just as confused. I think if they went the popup route, they would still get users complaining. (I personally know several who hate popups on mobile.)

Comment: @IMSoP [There is no review on the mobile layout.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available) Therefore, in this case, you'd end up with the same outcome- A disabled link or a popup explaining why you can't edit.

Comment: There are "popups" elsewhere on the mobile UI, though - I don't mean a massive window, just a small tooltip with an explanation. And there other links that lead you to pages without a mobile template, too - I can actually get to the edit review queue via other links, even if it doesn't look great.

Comment: I'm not disbelieving your evidence, by the way, I just don't agree with the reasoning of making bits of UI appear and disappear with no explanation.

Comment: @IMSoP I read a bit too fast over the answer I found- It's _is_ there on mobile, it's just not designed for mobile. At the same time, that does explain why they don't link it from a question via the edit link- If it's not designed for mobile, why would they want to give you easy access to it through mobile. If you disagree with how the UI is made, that'd be a topic for another post. This question only asked why you didn't get the edit link.

Comment: Well, [the close-as-duplicate dialogue is pretty hideous on mobile, too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171199/close-as-a-duplicate-on-mobile-lots-of-vertical-scrolling) but it's still linked to in the normal way. :P More relevantly, now that the edit is approved, I can click into the question's history as normal, which takes me to a non-mobile screen, complete with links through to the Review history.

Comment: But you're right, if I could be bothered, I'd raise a feature-request on MSE to make this consistent, but you have answered my question, thanks.